# How do I make css scroll snap work properly?

Tags: css

I have next slider, but I want mandatory `snap property` of the container to work properly and I have no idea what is wrong. I'd be grateful if someone will find out a miskate. It is set at fixme comment in css. code:

```css
body {
  background:orange;
}

@keyframes tonext {
  75% {
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  98% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  99% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes tostart {

  75% {
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  98% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  99% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes snap {
  96% {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
  97% {
    scroll-snap-align: none;
  }
  99% {
    scroll-snap-align: none;
  }
  100% {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
}

#carousel {
  width:100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans, sans-serif;
  color: #464646;
}

#carousel .carousel__viewport::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display:none;
}

#carousel ol, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#carousel .carousel {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 75%;
}

#carousel .carousel__viewport {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  counter-reset: item;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory; /*fixme*/
  max-width: 414px;
}

#carousel .carousel__slide {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width:300px;
  height:250px;
  background-color: green;
  counter-increment: item;
  outline:none;
  text-align: center;
}

#carousel .carousel__slide:nth-child(even) {
  background:red;
}

#carousel .carousel__slide:before {
  content: counter(item);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-40%,70px);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
}

/* автопрокрутка */
/* #carousel .carousel__snapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
} */

@media (hover: hover) {
  #carousel .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: tonext, snap;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }

  #carousel .carousel__slide:last-child .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: tostart, snap;
  }
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  #carousel .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: none;
  }
}

#carousel .carousel:hover .carousel__snapper,
#carousel .carousel:focus-within .carousel__snapper {
  animation-name: none;
}

#carousel .carousel__navigation {
  max-width:414px;
  text-align: center;
}

#carousel .carousel__navigation-list,
#carousel .carousel__navigation-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

#carousel .carousel__navigation-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #bababa;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 4px 0 4px;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

#carousel .carousel::before,
#carousel .carousel::after,
#carousel .carousel__prev,
#carousel .carousel__next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 37.5%;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

#carousel .carousel::before,
#carousel .carousel__prev {
  left: -1rem;
}

#carousel .carousel::after,
#carousel .carousel__next {
  right: -1rem;
}

#carousel .carousel::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,50 80,100 80,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

#carousel .carousel::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='100,50 20,100 20,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

#carousel .item {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 290px;
  width:320px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#carousel h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
#carousel h3.ready-store {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
#carousel ul {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#carousel li {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 0 0 10px 14px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
#carousel li:before {
  content: '';
  background: #464646;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 9px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section id='carousel' class="carousel" aria-label="Gallery">
  <ol class="carousel__viewport">
    <li id="carousel__slide1" tabindex="0" class="carousel__slide"></li>
    <li id="carousel__slide2" tabindex="0" class="carousel__slide"></li>
    <li id="carousel__slide3" tabindex="0" class="carousel__slide"></li>
  </ol>

  <aside class="carousel__navigation">
    <ol class="carousel__navigation-list">
      <a href='#carousel__slide1' class="carousel__navigation-item"></a>
      <a href='#carousel__slide2' class="carousel__navigation-item"></a>
      <a href='#carousel__slide3' class="carousel__navigation-item"></a>
    </ol>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Please make sure that you run this as mobile for left&right scrolling using finger to see overflow:scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting `scroll-snap-align` property for your carousel slides ([check it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-align)):

```
#carousel .carousel__slide {
  /* rest of css */
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}

@keyframes tonext {
  75% {
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  98% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  99% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes tostart {
  75% {
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  98% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  99% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes snap {
  96% {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
  97% {
    scroll-snap-align: none;
  }
  99% {
    scroll-snap-align: none;
  }
  100% {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
}

#carousel {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans, sans-serif;
  color: #464646;
}

#carousel .carousel__viewport::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#carousel ol,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#carousel .carousel {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 75%;
}

#carousel .carousel__viewport {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  counter-reset: item;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  /*fixme*/
  max-width: 414px;
}

#carousel .carousel__slide {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  counter-increment: item;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  /* added this */
}

#carousel .carousel__slide:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}

#carousel .carousel__slide:before {
  content: counter(item);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -40%, 70px);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
}


/* автопрокрутка */


/* #carousel .carousel__snapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
} */

@media (hover: hover) {
  #carousel .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: tonext, snap;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  #carousel .carousel__slide:last-child .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: tostart, snap;
  }
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  #carousel .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: none;
  }
}

#carousel .carousel:hover .carousel__snapper,
#carousel .carousel:focus-within .carousel__snapper {
  animation-name: none;
}

#carousel .carousel__navigation {
  max-width: 414px;
  text-align: center;
}

#carousel .carousel__navigation-list,
#carousel .carousel__navigation-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

#carousel .carousel__navigation-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #bababa;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 4px 0 4px;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

#carousel .carousel::before,
#carousel .carousel::after,
#carousel .carousel__prev,
#carousel .carousel__next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 37.5%;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

#carousel .carousel::before,
#carousel .carousel__prev {
  left: -1rem;
}

#carousel .carousel::after,
#carousel .carousel__next {
  right: -1rem;
}

#carousel .carousel::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,50 80,100 80,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

#carousel .carousel::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='100,50 20,100 20,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

#carousel .item {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 290px;
  width: 320px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#carousel h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

#carousel h3.ready-store {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

#carousel ul {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#carousel li {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 0 0 10px 14px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

#carousel li:before {
  content: '';
  background: #464646;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 9px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section id='carousel' class="carousel" aria-label="Gallery">
  <ol class="carousel__viewport">
    <li id="carousel__slide1" tabindex="0" class="carousel__slide"></li>
    <li id="carousel__slide2" tabindex="0" class="carousel__slide"></li>
    <li id="carousel__slide3" tabindex="0" class="carousel__slide"></li>
  </ol>

  <aside class="carousel__navigation">
    <ol class="carousel__navigation-list">
      <a href='#carousel__slide1' class="carousel__navigation-item"></a>
      <a href='#carousel__slide2' class="carousel__navigation-item"></a>
      <a href='#carousel__slide3' class="carousel__navigation-item"></a>
    </ol>
  </aside>
</section>
```